# Getting 'FileNotFoundException' when deploying Orleans 7.0 on Kubernetes - how to solve it?

Tags: asp.net-core, orleans, asp.net-core-7.0

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly The system cannot find the file specified. Orleans cannot load interface assembly

Dear all,
I am using Orleans 7.0
here you can see my project structure
[image]

When deployment the solution locally on different nodes (MyServerSilo and MyWebApp), everytging works fine.

When I deploy on a kubernetes cluster, I get the following error:

`FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyInterfaces, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
Orleans.Serialization.Invocation.ResponseCompletionSource<TResult>.GetResult(short token) in ResponseCompletionSource.cs
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>+ValueTaskSourceAsTask+<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(object state)
MyServiceLib.EmailAndActivationTokenService.Create(ActivationToken activationToken) in EmailAndActivationTokenService.cs
MyWebAppLib.Pages.Authentification.ChangePassWord.ChangePassWordStep1Model.OnPostSendChangePassWordMailAsync() in ChangePassWordStep1Model.cshtml.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod.Convert<T>(object taskAsObject)`
```

I have controlled that MyInterfaces has code generated inside his assembly.

Please can someone point me on what I am missing here?
Best regards

Comment: I don't see the correlation between the "FileNotFoundException" and the stacktrace tou posted.

Comment: When you run the container locally - is MyInterfaces.dll presented in the image? It looks like you have a problem with Dockerfile.